# Laravel4: upload a image

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want upload photo through a form. I have the Photo resource properly set up. The table photo with: id, title, caption, path:string.

This is part of the form that ask user to upload the image:

```
{{Form::open(array('route' => 'CrewRegisterPost', 'role'=>'form','files'=> true,'class' => 'form-horizontal','style' => 'margin-top:15px;'))}}
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="license_image">Colour scanned copy of Licence *</label>  
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <input type="file" name="license_image" accept="image/*" required>   
           {{Form::showError('license_image')}}         
    </div>
{{Form::close()}}
```

This is the simple store method i made until now:

```
public function createNewCrew($data){
        $user = $this->storeNewUserCommonFields($data,User::getTypeNumberFor('Crew'));

        $validator = new Saarang\Validators\FlightCrewValidator($data);

        if($validator->fails()){
            $this->messageBag->merge($validator->errors->getMessages());
        }

        if($user){
            $Crew = new Crew();
            $Crew->user_id = $user->getKey();
            $Crewlicense_image = $data['license_image'];
            $savepath = 'public/img/';
            $filename = time() . '-' .$Crewlicense_image;
            Input::file('license_image')->move($savepath, $filename);
            $Crew->save();
            return $user;
       }
}
```

> But when I run it I get the following error: Call to a member function
>   move() on a non-object

How can i put correctly there that implementation to retrieve the file and store in the folder located in public/img?

Comment: at first you should make a form and set the enctype attribute to multipart form data, and then put your input in the above form.

Comment: Just as an advice , dropzone plugin helped me alot .

Answer (score 0):

Try using:-

```
move(base_path().savepath, $filename);
```

instead of

```
move($savepath, $filename);
```

Because without writing **base_path()** method shows this types of errors.

Hope this will work for you.